# web2py form creation

Tags: forms, api, web2py

I'm trying to create a form in web2py.
I'm not sure on the correct syntax and don't understand from the examples in the site how this is done. Could someone give a better explanation?

How is a simple form like this created?

```
<form> 
<select> 
<option>Paint</option>
<option>Brushes</option>
<option>Erasers</option>
</select>
Quantity: <input type="text" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

How can I validate more complex forms?

Comment: Have you read the [forms chapter](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7) of the book? Please go through it, try something, and come back with a more specific question. To incorporate validations, it will probably be easiest to use `SQLFORM` or `SQLFORM.factory`.

Comment: What have you tried? Experiment with simple contollers like: ``def some_controller(): form= FORM(INPUT(...), SELECT('Paint', 'Brushers', 'Erasers')) return dict(form=form)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
items = ['Paint','Brushes','Erasers']
form = FORM(
    SELECT(*items),
    INPUT('Quantity', _type='text'),
)

return dict(form=form)
```

(in view):

```
{{ extend 'layout.html' }}

{{ =form}}
```

To validate this form, or a "more complex" form:

(in controller)

```
 form = FORM(...) # This is the same form def as above, must be before form.process() 

 if form.process().accepted:
     # Valid!
 else:
     # invalid.
```

If you have a more specific question, I'll attempt to answer it, but I highly recommend you check out the book and try to create and validate your own simple forms. You can use the welcome app as a place to start. Or you could google around for web2py apps and download and play with them.

Read these two chapters in their entirety and I'll help you with anything web2py in the future (there will be a quiz!):

Database Abstraction layer (important for unlocking the full power of web2py's DB-driven forms):
http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/6

Forms and Validators (everything you ever needed to know about creating forms and linking it to data:
http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7

Comment: Note, `SELECT([OPTION(x) for x in *items])` should be `SELECT([OPTION(x) for x in items])` (no asterisk before `items`). In fact, there is a simpler syntax -- if you just pass a set of items or a list to `SELECT()`, they will automatically be wrapped in `OPTION()` elements -- so you can do `SELECT(*items)` or even just `SELECT(items)`.

Comment: oops -- my bad. I was thinking SELECT(*items) but list comprehensions are so fun! Thanks.